# How to throttle Windows 10 update download

Tags: windows-update

I was prompted to update Windows this morning. I proceeded to do so.

After restarting, I got a further prompt for updates. So, I clicked on "Check For Updates". The resulting downloads are consuming my 12Mbps bandwidth and crippling my ability to work from home. Why would anyone design an update process this way?

I followed [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-bandwidth-limits-for-background-downloads-49c28a83-35c2-7f30-dfdc-802b4dd44e51)'s steps to throttle download bandwidth.
I enabled the checkboxes and slid the sliders to 11% for both background and foreground updates. Neither has any impact on the bandwidth usage.

**Why does both slides fail to throttle impact?**

**What other measures can I take?**  I have work to do.

Comment: They are probably for future updates. You would want to reboot your computer to break the download and resume it so it can take the new settings in effect.

Comment: I'm hesitant to do that because it is in the process of downloading.  Now it is in the process of update.  What I want to do is throttle when it is downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
in run (Windows key + R) type **gpedit.msc**
Then go to `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Delivery Optimization`
Double-click the Maximum Download Bandwidth (percentage) policy (the equivalent to the "Download settings" option in the Settings app).

Select the Enabled option.

Under "Options," enter the download bandwidth speed.

Click Apply and Ok.

Comment: Thanks, Mantas. Unfortunately, I can't test it right now, as the download has finished and the installation restart has hijacked my computer for what seems like a very long time.  I am incensed.  It would be dead simple to provide a warning of these protracted updates so that users can migrate their immediate work to other machines, or hold off for a better time.

Comment: This is ridiculous. You can't enter a fixed number, so even at 5% it still leeches the whole upstream bandwidth and starves other network devices. I'm so done with Windows. Can't even update without being flaky. Time to just delete those last few Win VMs. Not worth the upkeep.